# Crm 2011 custom web service

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to be able to extend CRM 2011 which is running in the cloud. I need to be able to perform CRUD operations from a completely separate internet web site. What options do I have? I have zero experience with CRM. I just found out that the OOB web services can only be accessed within the context of CRM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I just found out that the OOB web services can only be accessed within the context of CRM.

This is only true for the REST endpoint. Not for the other endpoints. You can access the [IOrganizationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309449.aspx) if you use .NET as basis or you could access the web services via SOAP.

- [Use the WSDL Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509052.aspx)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2011/03/22/crm-online-2011-web-services-soap-sample-now-ready-for-emea-amp-asia.aspx

Answer (score 1):

CRM 2011 exposes webservices through oData and SOAP endpoints. If you are using CRM 2011 Online you can hit these endpoints over the internet. If hosting CRM yourself, you can set it up for IFD (Internet Facing Deploy). I would suggest taking a look at the [CRM 2011 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=420f0f05-c226-4194-b7e1-f23ceaa83b69) for oData and SOAP examples.